# retrieving json data in cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I need to make a ajax call to retrieve data(json) from the RESTfull Web Service which is running in the different domain(KARAF using cxf) and the client from which the ajax call is being made, is on different domain(Apache Tomcat).

The Web Service is returning the data in the form of MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON but due to cross domain call I am receiving the data in the form of jsonp object.

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:8181/cxf/view/ID_123",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain : true,
    contentType: "applicaion/json",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback : 'myJsonCallBack',
    sucess : function(json) {
        alert("Success Called");
    },
    error : function(xhr) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

and the myJsonCallBack funcation is as below..

```
function myJsonCallBack(data) {
    alert("Callback Called");
}
```

The web service method is as below..

```
@GET
@Path("/view/{userid}")
public ViewPreference getViewPreference(@PathParam("userid") String userId) {
    ViewPreference viewPreference = new ViewPreference("GRID VIEW");
    return viewPreference;
}
```

which is returning json object as below..

```
{
    "viewPreference": {
        "preference": "GRID VIEW"
    }
}
```

The problem is when ever I make a ajax call neither the success callback runs nor the myJsonCallBack only error is run.

while checking in firebug it is showing some syntax error telling **SyntaxError: missing ; before statement {"viewPreference":{"preference":"GRID VIEW"}}.**

How to resolve this problem..?

Comment: i guess error is because you have specified dataType : "jsonp" in ajax and web service is returning JSON reponse instead of jsonp responce

Comment: Hi Dave, I used both the dataType but while using json as dataType the request type GET automatically changes to OPTIONS and no result found.

Answer (score 0):

here's what you should do:

you should return this from the server:

**'myJsonCallBack({"viewPreference": {"preference": "GRID VIEW"}})'**

rather than this: **{"viewPreference": {"preference": "GRID VIEW"}}**

this will call the myJsonCallback function and others without syntax errors

hope this helps :)